# How to add links to the list of cities?

Tags: javascript

there are dependent lists. How to add page links to cities?

```
<select name="country" id="country">
        <option value="bra">Браpилия</option>
        <option value="rus">Россия</option>
        <option value="ind">Индия</option>
        <option value="chn">Китай</option>
        <option value="zaf">ЮАР</option>
    </select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tfmv601/

Comment: Where to want link to be added? in the city option value?

Comment: Please explain little more what actually you want ? onchage link browse?

Comment: Take a ook at the linked fiddle, I suspect mr.cracker wants his `cities` select input to be populated with cities from the selected `country` input on a change event.

Comment: Where to want link to be added? in the city option value? yes

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option value="bra.php">a</option>
 <option value="rus.php">b</option>
 <option value="ind.php">c</option>
 <option value="chn.php">d</option>
 <option value="zaf.php">e</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an event listener that listens to the country select for input.
This can be done as follows:

in JS:
`country.setEventListener('change', selectCountry);`
OR
`country.onchange = selectCountry();`
OR in plain HTML
`<select onchange="selectCountry()" name="city" id="city">`